# Update Manager message "New Hardware Support is Available"

Tags: update-manager, hardware-enablement-stack

I haven't seen this message from Update Manager before, and I have not been able to google up any info.  What will be installed when I click Install?  (Clicking "Description of Update" got me nothing...)

Comment: There should be an `Details`-link/button somewhere... you might need to click up some more info first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple, really. Ubuntu 14.04 is now out, so what the Ubuntu developers did was make an update that makes Ubuntu 12.04 compatible with all of the same hardware Ubuntu 14.04 is compatible with in the form of an update. This makes Ubuntu 12.04 work with more computers, but if you're already running Ubuntu 12.04 just fine and all of your hardware is working properly, then this update probably won't do anything beneficial to you. I still strongly recommend that you install it anyway, even if all of your hardware is working right.

Comment: My main worry with applying the update is that it might break stuff for me. I tried 14.04 and had trouble getting the external monitor to work. I works without a hitch on 12.04. If indeed this update brings me on par with 14.04 re hardware support, it may be a bad thing for me.

Comment: Was scary :-) But I took a chance and installed it. It didn't break my 12.04. Actually, an improvement, it now recognizes more resolutions on my laptop's built-in display. Good job ubuntu devs :-)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I bit on it and clicked install.  It then gave the desired info via a link to this web page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

Comment: Update went fine, BTW.

Comment: Except see http://askubuntu.com/questions/496982/12-04-after-hwe-upgrade-and-running-ubuntu-tweak-to-clean-cruft-cant-start-lig

Answer (score 2):

It looks mandatory to me since the link (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL) said:

> Starting Aug 8, 2014 systems running 12.04.2 HWE, 12.04.3 HWE, or 12.04.4 HWE will no longer receive software updates for the kernel and, if you're running it, the graphics stack.

So there will be no more update for those who are running old HWE stacks (e.g. fresh install from 12.04.x ISO)...

I think the Update Manager should give us more info besides that simple "Install" button hanging over there.

[image: Update Manager Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on an answer because I don't have enough rep, but my husband did that update on Precise and it completely hosed up his system and he had to do a total re-install. So my advice would be if you are running Precise 12.04, don't do that upgrade. We spent hours trying to repair his system because of it.

It sure would be great if, instead of just putting the message and an install button in the update center, they would leave a link to let you know what it was all about.

Comment: When I just did the update it went ok...but when I ran Ubuntu Tweak to remove the old stuff, the results were disastrous.  It took a day or so to get back to functionality.  If I hadn't had more than one system so I could compare the working to non working, I might have bought a ticket to Reinstall City myself.