# New hardware support install error

Tags: software-installation, update-manager

using Ubuntu 12.04 I got the ["New Hardware Support is Avaliable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496881/update-manager-message-new-hardware-support-is-available) message in my Update manager. After trying to install I got an error-message that the Package dependencies cannot be resolved:

[image: Package dependencies cannot be resolved]

I tried to install libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty and the other two manually, but I aborted the install because it would have uninstalled too many things I don't know and I didn't want to risk to uninstall.

Is this a known bug? Or what else could be the reason for this error?

Comment: you are using ubuntu 12.04 (saucy salamander)saucy how can you install ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Thar) trusty packages??

Comment: @Creator Thats the prompt I got, don't ask me for details. Following instructions from the duplicate post does the trick.