# What to choose when both updates: (1) New Hardware Support available and (2) New ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS are available?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, hardware

A month ago, The update manager was showing a message

> new hardware support available    --Download.

Today Update manager again shows two messages:

> New Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS is available---upgrade
>
> new hardware support available    --Download

I am wondering which options to choose. Should I download the hardware stack first then upgrade to 14.04? Or only one? Or none at all?

Comment: For info on the HWE see http://askubuntu.com/questions/496881/update-manager-message-new-hardware-support-is-available

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade to  14.04.1 LTS first as this may have some of the hardware support updates included;

After updating I would then check to see if the hardware support updates are still available.

This is my personal preference based on potentially saving some time although it shouldn’t make much difference as to what order you select to do it in!

The above is entirely based on weather you want to upgrade you have that option also :)